# How to update with DatagridView without SQLAdapter

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I'm creating a backend for one of webpage. The backend is a Windows Form in C#.

I have a Business Object PaymentExpected:

```
public class PaymentExpected 
{
public int ID { get; set; }
public int JoiningID { get; set; }
public int AccountID { get; set; }
.....
 public List<PaymentExpected> Load_All()
{
 ....
}
```

And to fill my DataGridView I just do:

```
DG_View.DataSource = paymentExpected.Load_All();
```

now I want updates to be saved once the "Update" Button is clicked, But I dont want to use a SQL adapter as I use business objects.

So I need some way of getting the changes and calling the update. (Which I would normally update like this:)

```
paymentExpected.ID = 1;
paymentExpected.JoiningID = 1;
paymentExpected.AccountID = 1;
paymentExpected.Save();
```

But I am unsure of how to do that with the datagridview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you just keep a reference to the "paymentsExpected.Load_All()" data source in the code-behind and call paymentExpected.Save() from the button click event?

Comment: Hi, Im not really sure what you mean?  How do I pass the updated values to the object to save() ?

Comment: You are databinding so the changes should already bee in the bound object. From your example I guessed that you wanted to call Save() on the items bound to the datagridview.

Comment: Great! I didnt realise that it was binded and any actions I did would effect the List<BusinessObject>. But now I see that it does.

Comment: However, Next Question, is there a way I can get the exact object that has changed, instead of iterating through all objects and doing .save()?

Comment: I think you can answer that better than me, it really depends on your implementation of persistence. If your BusinessObject has a IsDirty property of sorts you can use that. The only way I think you can do it automagically is by using some AOP/interceptor logic and flag your objects as dirty if a property is touched. Use an ORM or Castle ActiveRecords or something which does the job for you. You should read up on persistance ignorance.